# SwiftUI: Make View portrait only on the iPhone, but both portrait and landscape on the iPad

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, screen-orientation

I have one specific SwiftUI View, that needs to be both landscape and portrait on the iPad, but should be only portrait on the iPhone. I've already seen some ways to implement it in UIKit, but nothing related to SwiftUI. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UIDevice.current.model` for checking device type. So, when you have both views (rotatable and not rotatable) you can just put them into `if...else` statements, based on device type:

```swift
struct RotateOniPadOnly: View {

    private var needsToRotate: Bool {
        return UIDevice.current.model == "iPad"
    }

    var body: some View {

        if needsToRotate {
            return AnyView(Text("rotated text")
                .font(.system(size: 100))
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 180)))
        } else {
            return AnyView(Text("not rotated text")
                .font(.system(size: 50)))
        }
    }

}


struct RotateOniPadOnly_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            RotateOniPadOnly()
                .previewDevice("iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)")

            RotateOniPadOnly()
        }

    }
}
```

the result should be:

[image]

**UPDATE**
according to question's editing I can propose [Changing a view’s layout in response to size classes tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/ios-swiftui/changing-a-views-layout-in-response-to-size-classes), it bases on `@Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var sizeClass` and I think you can find solution from it.

Comment: Actually, I meant screen orientation lock for a specific view, maybe I should've been more specific in my question

Comment: @AndreyViktorov , oh, I see. check answer's update, hope it'll help you